# I'm trying to host my domain on wamp

Tags: apache, iis-7, wamp, virtual-machine, vps

So I've uninstalled IIS7.5 for wamp to be online.
Idk why, when I typed "localhost" on my vps browser it works like I'm expected, but when i tried to type my domain/vps ip address into my home pc browser it returned "403 Forbidden" .

Comment: What's the programming question?

Answer (score 0):

Check the IP address of your domain. It should be 127.0.0.1. If not, you can fake it by editing your hosts file located at

`C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\` or `%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\`

Edit the file named 'hosts' and add the line:

`127.0.0.1 yourdomainname.com`

Also:

`127.0.0.1 localhost`

Should be included as one of the first lines.